# Setting bookcover parameters with bookcover package given width and height information

Tags: bookcover

The following shows the bookcover dimensions I need:

[image: Cover dimensions needed]

I'm using the bookcover package and have the following so far:

```
\documentclass[
    coverwidth=8.447in,
    coverheight=11.236in,
    spinewidth=0.367in,
    flapwidth=0in,
    wrapwidth=0.591in,
%    trimmed % Show only trimmed part!
    ]{bookcover}
```

Do I have the parameters set correctly?  I'm not clear how to account for the spine margins, for example, or if "coverheight" is the same as "Full Cover" or "Front Cover".

Comment: `zwpagelayout.sty` is one of the best package to typeset cover and spine and have easy documentation

Comment: On ctan you can find it here: https://ctan.org/pkg/zwpagelayout

Comment: Off-topic, but closely related, since you are using KDP: When you are finished, print the PDF on a home inkjet printer, or office copier, not using "photo quality". Does not matter if it has to shrink to fit on the paper. Are the colors satisfactory? If not, re-work your colors. The print-on-demand color space is more limited than what you can see on a computer screen.

Comment: @rallg This is a photography book too.  Good to know.  I was considering Lulu too but thought Amazon had better distribution.   Also, note that there is a "Premium Color" option now for hardcovers through KDP.

Comment: I doubt if it matters which POD service you use. I have used POD several times, but never "premium color". Instead, I have softproof capability (this is outside TeX) to emulate POD colors on screen. You might try this: Load the finished cover PDF into a graphics program with color management (GIMP can do it), rasterized at 300dpi. Use softproof mode, with "US Web Coated (SWOP) v2" as color profile. Or, FOGRA39 is just as good. If working with real-life photos, possibly no visible difference. If working with intense colors, they will change.

Comment: @rallg Softproof mode?  How do I find that in GIMP or the US Web Coated (SWOP) v2 color profile?  It's not coming up.

Comment: @rallg Got it.  Coated, not Uncoated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following settings correspond to the template shown.

```
\documentclass[
  coverwidth  = 8.447in,
  coverheight = 11.236in,
  spinewidth  = 0.367in,
  bleedwidth  = 0in,
  marklength  = 0.591in,
  ]{bookcover}

\letnamebookcoverpart{xspine}{spine}[0.062in,0.125in,0.062in,0.125in]
% The 'xspine' is an arbitrary name, which is the trimmed part of the spine.
% [<left margin>,<top margin>,<right margin>,<bottom margin>]
\letnamebookcoverpart{xfront}{front}[0.394in,0.125in,0.125in,0.125in]
\letnamebookcoverpart{xback}{back}[0.125in,0.125in,0.394in,0.125in]

\begin{document}

\begin{bookcover}

\begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{xspine}
color=lightgray
\end{bookcoverelement}

\begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{xfront}
color=lightgray
\end{bookcoverelement}

\begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{xback}
color=lightgray
\end{bookcoverelement}

\end{bookcover}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What does the positioning of xspine, xfront, and xback represent when you say `[0.062in,0.062in,0.062in,0.062in]`, for example?  I mean what does the white between the grey xspine and grey xfront represent, for example?  Or the white between the grey xfront and  vertical red trim lines?

Comment: xspine, xfront, and xback represent the margins indicated by the template?

Comment: xspine is the margin-trimmed part of spine. If you compare the parameters with those specified in the template, you will understand.

Comment: I wrote an explanation in the code.

Comment: Got it.  What about the white gap between the grey xfront and the vertical red trim marks?  Is that accounting for the bleedwifth around the edge?

Comment: You're right, it really wasn't fair, I looked it up. I corrected.

Comment: So the three white sections in the template I provided are the grey sections in your version?

Comment: Exactly right:)

Comment: What does `marklength` refer to?  I thought it produced the red marks but when I comment it out I still get them.

Comment: If the `marklength` option is commented out, the default value of `10mm` is used (see in [http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bookcover/bookcover.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/bookcover/bookcover.pdf))